# Built en Character For Unity3D

Tags: android, 3d, unity-game-engine

I am new in Unity.I am going to make 3D fighting game so I need character so that i can customize them in Unity and can start on my work.So can anyone tell me is there any way to get built en Character so that i can not waste my time to make character in Other 3D modeling just like MAYA etc... So can i found Character and make them customize with my needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several resources like Unity Asset Store, [Blendwap](http://www.blendswap.com), [3DExport.com](http://3dexport.com/), [Mixamo Autorigger](http://www.mixamo.com/c/automatic-rigging-for-blender-unity3d?utm_source=unity_blog), [TurboSquid](http://www.turbosquid.com/) and others, where you can find a lot of models off the shelf. But be warned:

Chances are very high that at the end you will find yourself tuning and customising in Blender, Maya or whatever tool you (don't) like ;-) There is almost always a need to change something and then you have to learn at least the basic concepts or find someone who does this for you. As you have tagged this question with Android, you have to bear in mind that you are limited to low-poly characters (<= 1000 vertices, <= 30 bones)

Comment: "  you have to bear in mind that you are limited to low-poly characters (<= 1000 vertices, <= 30 bones)  "                            Sorry i could't understand this thing.Would you please explain this thing...:)

Comment: @user1594794 See several discussions about mobile development like [polycount IOS / Android games?](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/255976/polycount-ios-android-games.html). While the manual page [Optimizing Graphics Performance](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html) states less than 100k vertices, in practice a skinned mesh with physics, etc. should not exceed 1000 to run at an acceptable frame rate.